# Spring Data JPA : How to write subquery having IN operator

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

How can I write the following subquery in Spring Data JPA?

```
select o from Owner o where o.ownerId IN (Select c.ownerId from Cars c)
```

Here `Owner` is one entity class and `Cars` is another entity class and I have two repositories: `OwnerRepository` and `CarRepository`, both extending `JPARepository`.

How to write the subquery having `IN` operator?

Answer (score 8):

You could always just use your query as a custom query:

```
@Query(value = "select o from Owner o where o.ownerId IN (Select c.ownerId from Cars c")
Owner getOwner();
```

If you need to pass variables to the query, use the `@Param` tag, like so:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Owner o WHERE o.ownerId = :id")
Owner getOwnerWithId(@Param("id") Long id);
```

Comment: Also take a look at [this](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-three-custom-queries-with-query-methods/)